# how can I loop over Api request for multiple keys and add a value to every loop?

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary, etl

How can I add a value to every loop with different API keys? I am trying to write a simple ETL for multiple store locations. My first attempt was to pull each API request individually. However, this will mean I have to duplicate the same code. Therefore, I decided to create a loop to iterate over the keys for every location. I want to Identify each transaction with a location Identifier. I want to add this identifier during the loop. I have included my attempt at solving this in python. Please provide some feedback and if this would be the correct approach.

```
all=[]
for key,value in api_data.items():
     header= {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Authorization': value,}
     res=requests.get(URL,headers=header)
     res_j=res.json()
     all.extend(res_j)
```

Comment: You  could replace `all` for a `dict` with `{key: res_j,...}` pairs. Or replace the value in `api_data` with `res_j`. And don't use `all` as a name; its a python method.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary keyed on the authorisation value. The associated value will be the returned JSON.

Always check the HTTP response.

In this case you only need *values()* from the *api_data* dictionary.

Something like this should help:

```
mydata = dict()
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
for value in api_data.values():
  headers['Authorization'] = value
  (res := requests.get(URL, headers=headers)).raise_for_status()
  mydata[value] = res.json()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I edit my question to hopefully clarify the outcome. @OlvinRoght